# How to set statuscode field by javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I have a problem with a simple javascript in CRM 2011:).
I have create a custom entity and a button on the form ribbon. When the button is pressed the following code is executed:

```
function Process(){
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("statuscode").setValue(229660003);
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
}
```

Now, also if the status reason is updated in the form, the record isn't saved..why?
If I change the statuscode with a custom field all work right but why with status reason so not work? With plugin code it aldo works.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's been a while but I think I found different behaviours between create and update with statuscode. It also matters if the particular statuscode value is valid for the current statecode

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem. The status reason was set as a read only field on the form so forcing the submitmode to always is possibile to change it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`statecode` and `statuscode` fields can't be updated as other fields, by JavaScript or by C# inside custom code or plugins.

It is necessary to execute a `SetStateRequest`

Comment: I may be wrong here but I think it is possible to update the **status** code in certain scenarios outside of a `SetStateRequest`

Answer (score 1):

As Guido Preite mentioned, It is necessary to execute a `SetStateRequest`. If you want to use JavaScript,  you need to make SOAP call.

Please check the solution here:

[Set Status or State of a Record](http://mileyja.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/set-status-or-state-of-record-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple .net  handler  which you can call from javascript using a xmlhttprequest.